# Getting Issue in Jenkins Continues Integration to HockeyApp in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, xcode8

All,

We are using Jenkins Continuous integration for App Uploads Below is the Script in Execute Shell in the Job.

**rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
rm -fr Pods/
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod install
xcodebuild -configuration Release -scheme MyApp_Test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace SYMROOT="${WORKSPACE}/MyApp/Build/"
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v  "${WORKSPACE}/MyApp/Build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp_Test.app" -o  "${WORKSPACE}/MyApp/Build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.ipa"**

Earlier it is working perfectly and able to the integration, Recently we updated he Xcode to 8.3.2, From then we are getting errors below are the Errors we are getting

**xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure**

Can any one help in solving the issue seems PackageApplication is deprecated and exportArchive is added, how can we change to that syntax

Comment: The `PackageApplication` option for `xcrun` has been removed with Xcode 8.3, you need to switch to using xcodebuild to do your build.

Answer (score 1):

```
Before: xcrun with PackageApplication
# Build the application
xcodebuild \
-scheme "${SCHEME_NAME}" \
-sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" \
-configuration Release build

# Package the application
/usr/bin/xcrun \
-sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" \
PackageApplication \
-v "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${SCHEME_NAME}.app" \
-o "${BUILD_OUTPUT_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.ipa" \
--sign "${DEVELOPER_NAME}" \
--embed "${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}"
After: xcodebuild with -exportArchive
# Archive the application
xcodebuild \
-scheme "${SCHEME_NAME}" \
-sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" \
-archivePath "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${SCHEME_NAME}.xcarchive" \
-configuration Release \
PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}" \
archive 

# Export the archive to an ipa
xcodebuild \
-exportArchive \
-archivePath "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${SCHEME_NAME}.xcarchive" \
-exportOptionsPlist "${EXPORT_PLIST}" \
-exportPath "${BUILD_OUTPUT_DIR}"
```